# How to prevent conflicts between Pods when using `use_framework!`?

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods

I am currently developing a React Native application, and as part of its functionality, I integrated a package called "react-native-text-input-mask." In order for my application to function properly, I need to include the `use_frameworks!` directive inside the main target of my Podfile. However, when I add this directive, and I run `arch -x86_64 pod install` I encounter the following error message:

[image: Error throwed by pod install]

This is my podfile that runs `pod install` successfully:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'NosRezo' do
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )
  
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'react-native-contacts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-contacts' 
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Batch', '~>1.18'

  target 'NosRezoTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  
 
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()
 
   post_install do |installer|
    `sed -i -e  $'s/__IPHONE_10_0/__IPHONE_12_0/' Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h`
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
      end
    end

    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end

end

target 'NosRezo-tvOS' do
  # Pods for NosRezo-tvOS

  target 'NosRezo-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'RichNotificationsExtension' do
  pod 'BatchExtension-ObjC'
end
```

I am currently working on my React Native application using a MacBook with the M2 chip.

Comment: Did you try `arch -arm64-darwin-22` too? Because that is what I would expect to be the correct arch on Apple Silicon?